# A die is rolled 10 times, what is the probability to get two 6's and three 5's

Tags: probability, combinatorics

hi i got this question and im trying to figure it out

a die is rolled 10 times, what is the probability of 
getting exactly two 6's and exactly three 5's ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Answer (score 2):

This is what you can call a case of "trinomial distribution".

There are $10$ independent and identical experiments and each of them has $3$ possible results: a $6$, a $5$ or something else.

The corresponding formula for probability is:$$\binom{10}{2,3,5}\left(\frac16\right)^2\left(\frac16\right)^3\left(\frac46\right)^5$$where $\binom{10}{2,3,5}$ is a notation for trinomial coefficient $\frac{10!}{2!3!5!}$.